# include an php scirpt for each request

Tags: php

I wonder if it is possible and include a php script that always runs for each file. I should not have to include the php script from the php file, but I want to be able to include a script that always runs from the php.ini or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`auto_prepend_file string`** in php.ini

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require function, so include_path is used.

Comment: The most easy solution for PHP scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. from php.ini seems easier. This avoid you to include on all PHP scripts you serve.

As you say "include a php script that always runs for EACH FILE" A big diference between php.ini auto_prepend_file directive, is in fact that this will work on PHP files, but not on static html one. With SSI you can server banner for ALL Apache request.

**The short asnwer is that:** You have to use SSI (Apache server side includes) to load an shtm file configuring directives. Now, you do the trick, load by javascript a php server file wherever you put it (full path, or remote url).

All belongs to Javascript, not the real PHP. So, on the embedded php page you can run any PHP stuff with easy.

No direct way to put PHP code and add as a banner to Apache serving pages.

**The long answer is:**
Read that sites:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html
- http://www.zytrax.com/tech/php/php_ssi.htm
- http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/ssi.htm